# Direction toward a point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Wikipedia gives the following [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set#Examples) of a directed set structure $ \preceq $ on the real numbers $ \mathbb{ R } $ given a real number $ c \in \mathbb{ R } $: for any real numbers $ x , y \in \mathbb{ R } $, we say that $ x \preceq y $ if and only if $ \left | x - c \right | \leq \left | y - c \right | $ (note that I have reversed the order from the example; this is gives a *downward* directed set, which is the same up to a reversal of order).

It's clear that this can easily be generalized to any pointed metric space; given a point $ c \in X $ in a metric space $ \left ( X , \rho \right ) $, we can construct a (downward) directed set structure $ \preceq $ as follows: for any points $ x , y \in X $, we say that $ x \preceq y $ if and only if $ \rho \left ( x , c \right ) \leq \rho \left ( y , c \right ) $. Moreover, a map $ f \colon X \to Y $ from this metric space $ \left ( X , \rho \right ) $ to a topological space $ \left ( Y , \tau \right ) $ converges at $ c $ to a limit $ \ell \in Y $ in the usual sense (as a map between topological spaces) if and only if this map converges to $ \ell $ as a net.

My question is, to what extent can this definition be generalized? Is there a directed set structure on any pointed topological space such that the above equivalence of types of convergence holds? That is, given a point $ c \in X $ in a topological space $ \left ( X , \tau_{ X } \right ) $, is there a (downward) directed set structure $ \preceq $ on $ X $ such that a map $ f \colon X \to Y $ from $ X $ to a topological space $ \left ( Y , \tau_{ Y } \right ) $ converges at $ c $ to a limit $ \ell \in Y $ as a map between topological spaces if and only if $ f $ converges as a net?

In my attempt to answer this question for myself, I found that if such a directed set structure exists, it is not necessarily unique, even if the topological space is metrizable. To see this, consider the following [example](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rtjgzbecpe) in the plane $ \mathbb{ R }^{ 2 } $. The point $ \left ( 0.6 , 0.6 \right ) $ is closer to the origin $ \left ( 0 , 0 \right ) $ than the point $ \left ( 1 , 0 \right ) $ in the Euclidean metric, but is farther from the origin than $ \left ( 1 , 0 \right ) $ when considered in the taxicab metric. So these metrics do not induce the same directed set structure on the plane $ \mathbb{ R }^{ 2 } $, even though they induce the same topology.

However, such a directed set structure may exist even for topological spaces which are not metrizable. Take a nonempty trivial topological space $ \left ( X , \tau_{ X } \right ) $ and a point $ c \in X $, and consider the equivalence relation $ \sim $ on $ X $ which identifies all points with each other; that is, $ { \sim } = X \times X $. This is an equivalence relation, and so is a preorder. Moreover, $ c \sim x $ and $ x \sim c $ for any point $ x \in X $, so $ \sim $ is a directed set structure on $ X $ (this is directed both upward and downward).

Now consider any map $ f \colon X \to Y $ from $ X $ to a topological space $ \left ( Y , \tau_{ Y } \right ) $. Then $ f $ converges at $ c $ to a point $ \ell \in Y $ if and only if for all neighborhoods $ V \subseteq Y $ of $ \ell $, there’s a neighborhood $ U \subseteq X $ of $ c $ such that $ f \left ( U \right ) \subseteq V $. Note that, since $ \left ( X , \tau_{ X } \right ) $ is trivial, $ X $ itself is the only neighborhood of $ c $, and so $ f $ converges at $ c $ to $ \ell $ if and only if the image of $ f $ is contained in every neighborhood of $ \ell $. Conversely, $ f $ converges to $ \ell $ as a net if and only if for all neighborhoods $ V \subseteq Y $ of $ \ell $, there is a point $ x_{ * } \in X $ such that $ f \left ( x \right ) \in V $ for all points $ x \in X $ such that $ x_{ * } \sim x $. By our definition of $ \sim $, this occurs if and only if the image of $ f $ is contained in every neighborhood of $ \ell $. So $ \sim $ is a directed set structure on $ X $ of precisely the type that we are looking for.

Comment: Hardly for *any* pointed topological space. Taking the trivial topology on $\mathbb R$ won't work. We need the space to fulfill some kind of separation axiom.

Comment: Actually, the equivalence relation which identifies all points with each other satisfies all of the desired properties for any trivial topological space. I encourage you to check that (1) this equivalence relation is a directed set structure; and (2) that a map from a trivial topological space converges to a point if and only if its image is contained in every neighborhood of that point, if and only if this map converges as a net (where the directed set structure is the equivalence relation above).

Comment: @md2perpe I just added a more in-depth explanation of the above to the original question.

Comment: I know, but I thought that you wanted convergence to a single point. You don't have that in the trivial topology.

Comment: @md2perpe You're 100% right that limits aren't unique in non-Hausdorff spaces, but you can still talk about convergent nets or maps.